# User unable to manage powerpivot refresh

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server, secure-store

I have a secure store application in SharePoint 2013. As an admin, I am able to go to "Manage PowerPivot Refresh" and update the information on the schedule and save.  However, I have set up an additional user as an admin.  she has full control in the library, she is an administrator on the target application, and even a farm admin.  However, when she tries to update the settings on "Manage PowerPivot Refresh" page, it says "The provided Secure Store target application is either incorrectly configured or does not exist."

The report refreshes using those exact settings nightly, however, I am trying to allow the new admin to refresh on demand using the "Also refresh as soon as possible."

She can refresh the report on demand when it is open in excel.  I am really just trying to troubleshoot the Secure Store Application issues.  I have done both an IIS reset and restarted the servers since updating the administrators on the target application. She also has read permissions at the database level.

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated!

Comment: is she in the list of "Members" on that target application? Also did you set the credentials?

Comment: Yes, she is a a member on the target application.  As to the set credentials, where or at what level should this be done.  I believe I have the credentials set up, but that could just be a miscommunication.

Comment: you just use the drop-down on the target application in the secure store, and choose set credentials, where is the account that the users will be "impersonating" as.

Comment: Still no luck!  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually resolved by running SharePoint Configuration wizard and restarting the servers after the user was involved.  This allowed the databases etc to refresh and then the user had no further problems.